# how to tell whether a tomcat installation is UTF-8 compatible?

Tags: tomcat, character-encoding

I am confronted with the tasks of telling whether tomcat servers in my organisation are able to process UTF-8. The tasks is as vague as it sounds here and I will answer as vague I assume. This all hapens on a larger scale, so I will use Ansible to do this.

Now, without any expertize in tomcat I am wondering what could be a parameter or setting to look for in order to provide such a statement (*"server xy can/cannot talk UTF-8"*).

for database server (postgres & mariadb) I can get this info right from the database itself and I am guessing I might need to check entries in configuration files of tomcat for getting a hint in this regards.

So, my question is ... what should I look for? `~/conf/server.xml` or `~/conf/web.xml` (which in one example here has some mentioning of UTF-8 actually) come to mind.

Or is this maybe an obsolete question to begin with because something like tomcat does not even care about character-encoding (as I said, my expertize is quite limited) here?

A colleague mentioned I should look into JDBC drivers (which I neither know anything about).

Comment: Some [info](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/get-utf-8-encoding-work-tomcat-buddhika-nuwan-dahanayake) on that.

Comment: thx, looks like it's a bundle of things to look for.

Answer (score 2):

I'd encourage you to read the official documentation for how to [configure Tomcat character encoding](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding).

I'd especially direct you to the "Why does everything have to be this way" part of that document, because it explains why it's not so straightforward to configure things properly. It's not just one "do UTF-8 everywhere" setting, and that section explains why such a thing does not exist. It's difficult to provide such a setting, since Tomcat's configuration can be ignored by an application which itself must be UTF-8-aware.